# has_post_thumbnail() Returns False on Scheduled Posts

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, scheduled-posts

I am making some changes to a custom WP template and have hit an odd issue. Published posts work absolutely fine, but when you view a scheduled post the Featured Image disappears.

It's as if there was no featured image at all and `has_post_thumbnail()` returns false. Here's the relevant piece of code I'm working with, relatively simple stuff really:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
    $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
  }
}
```

And again, this works fine on published posts but as soon as I set the date to the future the image stops coming through.  It seems strange that images would be treated differently based on the publish date, is there anything which WP changes on scheduled posts vs live posts which could be causing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, your code works for me with a scheduled post. verify it's not a theme or plugin related issue by disabling plugins and using a core theme.

Comment: Although it's working for me but why are you supplying post ID if you are using function inside the loop. You can simply use this `if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); }`

Comment: @Roberthue It hink you should post your comment as answer with a littel expanded explanation.

Comment: @Roberthue I have tried with and without, doesn't seem to make a difference, there must be something strange in the functions.php or a plugin perhaps, I'll keep digging.

Comment: It seems that the reason for `has_post_thumbnail()` failing is because `get_post_meta()` returns empty, still looking in to why that is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that the reason `has_post_thumbnail()` was failing was because `get_post_meta()` was returning empty for scheduled posts. I'm still not sure why, but in case someone else has the issue, my workaround was to create a new function to fetch the featured image ID without relying on `get_post_meta()`:

```
function get_featured_image_id($postID) {
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'", $postID));
    if (!empty($data[0]->meta_value)) {
        return $data[0]->meta_value;
    }
}
```

Then you can get a featured image URL in your template with the following line:

```
wp_get_attachment_url(get_featured_image_id($post->ID))
```

Answer (score -2):

Its too much simple

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $featuredImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID,'full'));
        echo $featuredImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a proper explanation to how your code work and how it should be used. *Its too much simple* is not a valid explanation. Please file an [edit]

Comment: You also have syntax errors in your code, you cannot use `:` and curlies together, you either use `{}` or `:` and `endXXX`

Comment: ok @PieterGoosen

Comment: The issue is that has_post_thumbnail() returns false for scheduled posts. Unfortunately this solution doesn't address that.

Comment: @AndrewSpear There minnar problem use " ;(sc) " and not start Brakets ok please open your eyes